# Regex, target a char, but not if it a part of certain word

Tags: c#, regex

It must be said that I'm not very experienced at RE. I've been looking several examples but nothing seems to suit my needs. Currently I have:

```
            Regex pattern = new Regex("[x]");
```

But I don't want to select the "x" if it's inside the word "Exp". How can I do this?

`Exp(x)` --> I need only to target the x inside the brakets

I've tried `"[^Exp][x]" "(?Exp)[x]"` and variations, without getting the desired result.

Comment: You mean you want to match only when `[x]` found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using word boundaries:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\bx\b");
```

Also, the `@` avoids you the task of double escaping.

A word boundary is a special character which will match between a letter, digit or underscore and a non-letter/non-digit/non-underscore. Basically, if you have `aa`, `\b` will match only at the start and end, not in the middle. If you have `a.2c`, `\b` will match before `a`, between `a` and the `.`, between `.` and `2`, and after `c`, but not between `2` and `c`. You can get more info on [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

---

Also, if you want to get an `x` which is in brackets, you can use lookarounds:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<=\()x(?=\))");
```

`(?<=\()` is a positive lookbehind and checks to make sure there's an opening paren before `x`.

`(?=\))` is a positive lookahead and checks to make sure there's a closing paren after `x`.

Comment: @Sturm A word boundary is a special character which will match between a letter, digit or underscore and a non-letter/non-digit/non-underscore. Basically, if you have `aa`, `\b` will match only at the start and end, not in the middle. If you have `a.2c`, `\b` will match before `a`, between `a` and the `.`, between `.` and `2`, and after `c`, but not between 2 and c